# Level selection "map" velocity Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am creating a game in which you select the levels on a map of a town, like in Granny Smith or Candy Crush. You drag the the map to reveal more levels ( the map being a group with level pictures and a background in it). I used the drag function from the sample project. It works perfectly, but it is not smooth at all. When the map is released after being dragged,I want it to continue in that direction, and slow down and stop instead of stopping as soon as the map is released. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this:

```
local target = 100
local tapDrag = function(e) player.y = (player.y*10 + target) / 11 end
Runtime:addEventListener( "touch", function(e) target = e.y end)
Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", tapDrag )
```

This would make it so the object would be smooth on the Y axis. You could also make this work for the X Axis too. Good luck

Comment: Thanks for responding! This works great, but it only works if you touch the map on one position (about 400 down). Once you scroll down, it moves back up to the top to scroll down again.

Comment: You might have to adjust the target value. This is meant to tap in one location on the screen, then the object goes to that location.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I will modify it to match what I need!